Using the same scatter geometry node setup twice breaks density input
I made myself a quick little scatter geo node to make the creation of outdoor environments easier.
I need to scatter two seperate objects on the same plane, so I create two different scatter modifiers on my plane.
The problem is that on the second scatter, whenever I click on Switch to attribute next to the density input, all it does is completely break the first scatter's density input.

(Notice how the top Scatter's Density input switches back to float)
This happens even if I duplicate my geometry node and use that duplicate as my second modifier.
Does anyone know what could be happening and how it could be fixed ?
Thanks !
(Here's the scatter.blend for those who want to investigate further)

if you add a 2nd GN modifier after your first scatter, of course this behaves totally different because the input geometry of the 2nd scatter isn't the same (a plane) but the whole output geometry of your first GN. Unfortunately your switch node in your example is connected to nothing, so it is not clear how you connected that. Solution is either to copy your plane as object with  and do the one scattering on one plane and the other scattering on the other with maybe the same GN node tree but different input values or you make one GN node tree with 2 scatterings.

Yeha that switch node is just a remnant, I didn't use it. So basically the solution would be to edit the GN to entirely support having a second scatter?

one solution, yes
